# Send notification when apache is down

Tags: linux, apache, notifications

Are there any possibilities / options to set the notification when apache is down.

When apache is down, .htaccess file will work?

When the script running on the background in mid night, in the mid of the execution apache server is down / crash, can we set any notification.

Adding few steps for better understanding

step 1 program started
step 2 variables initialized
step 3 Read load file, get records from file
step 4 insert above file contents into into table-x.
step 5 close db connection

CRON doing above action every one hour.

After above step 3, APACHE crash / down, now i want to send notification to system admin through email. let me know step by step action plan.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this. There we services that will monitor your server, or you could set up a cron job. But it's not entirely clear what you're asking. An `.htaccess` file doesn't *do* anything; if Apache is offline, the file has no purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly [whip up a script](http://www.anyexample.com/linux_bsd/bash/check_if_program_is_running_with_bash_shell_script.xml) to check if Apache is down. However, I recommend using another server - perhaps a micro instance on AWS or something like that - that tries to wget your site. If it is able to access the site, great. Otherwise, it can send notification to you. Or you could use [some services](http://mashable.com/2010/04/09/free-uptime-monitoring/#wQRMXsfi.Sqd) that can monitor whether your site appears up or not.

You could also use services such as AWS Route 53 to switch traffic to another standby server or a maintenance page hosted on another server indicating to users that your site is temporarily offline or something like that.

Comment: so mean, we have use tool called "splunk "

Comment: In your edited question, you mention about 5 steps. Are they done through a bash script? If so, after each step, you can check success of the step and only proceed further if there was success; otherwise send out a mail notification. OR - if a step depends on httpd, check if httpd is running using something like `service apache2 status` or whatever command is applicable before going to the dependent step

Comment: sounds good, good idea, but looking some server end instead of code, bcoz when script halt we will not get any resp,